# centos kickstart still has 60 second wait for automatic boot

Tags: centos, centos7, kickstart

Is there any kickstart or boot option I can use to tell CentOS7 to automatically boot.

Currently I'm still getting below 60 second wait before the kickstart install to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Did you modify this ISO image to add a kickstart? What did you do?

Comment: I'm using an unedited centos ISO. The kickstart is sperate ISO and is picked up using OEMDRV label. As per docs https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-howto#sect-kickstart-installation-starting

Comment: @DarVar did you figure this out?